# How can the title be forced inside the legend box when using \n

Tags: r, plot, legend

I made a legend to my plot, however the title takes up too much space when left in one line. The problem occurs when I code the title to be in two separate lines; the lower sentence is inside the legend box, while the upper part of the sentence is outside the legend, interfering with the main title of the plot. Is there a way to force the legend title inside the legend box when separating the title in two lines?

```
par(mar=c(3,3,2,3),xpd=T)
legend(col=c(1:5),
       "topright",inset=c(-0.28,0),
       legend=c("0", "10", "20", "30", "40"),pch=c(1:5), 
       title=" Dosage :\n (mg/L)")
```